# PHP extract string after second comma

Tags: php, string

I have a string shown below and I would like to extract the string after the second comma.  Thanks in advance.

> Last Name, First Name, Giberish String

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than going for complicated REGEXs, just use `explode()`.

```
$string = 'Last name, First name, Giberish';
$array = explode(', ', $string);
$giberish = $array[2];
```

See in action: https://3v4l.org/16ABc

Comment: Woops, thanks. Will update! Correct answer is also in the linked example, so OP could have figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSV parser for this, and then just iterate over the array for all values after the second index (which would be the second comma):

```
$return = '';
$string = 'Last Name, First Name, Giberish String';
$values = str_getcsv($string);
foreach($values as $key => $value){
    if($key >= 2) {
        $return .= trim($value);
    }
}
```

or a regex could be used:

```
$return = '';
$string = 'Last Name, First Name, Giberish String';
preg_match('/^(?:.*?,){2}\s*\K.*/', $string, $match);
$return = $match[0];
```

https://regex101.com/r/Vh37FU/1/

Comment: Both answers are unreadable as hell, but props for finding a regex and out-of-the-box solution with the csv parser.

Comment: I have no trouble reading this answer's codes.